# How to implement OAuth to FastAPI with client ID & Secret

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I have followed the docs about Oauth2 but it does not describe the proccess to add client id and secret

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/

and what this does

```
class UserInDB(User):
    hashed_password: str
```

from the original example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In documentation it uses `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` to authenticate the user this class has basically 6 different Fields,

```
grant_type: str = Form(None, regex="password"),
username: str = Form(...),
password: str = Form(...),
scope: str = Form(""),
client_id: Optional[str] = Form(None),
client_secret: Optional[str] = Form(None),
```

So you can add `client_id` and `client_secret`,if you are interested [Repository](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/security/oauth2.py) here.

But i usally prefer [**`authlib`**](https://github.com/lepture/authlib), it saves so much time makes it easier. Here is a complete example of how you can create a OAuth with authlib

First create a OAuth Client

```
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
from starlette.config import Config

config = Config('.env')  # read config from .env file
oauth = OAuth(config)
oauth.register(
    name='google',
    server_metadata_url='https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid email profile'
    }
)
```

We don't need to add client_id and client_secret here, because they are in .env file. You are not supposed to hard code them in the code in real products.Google has an OpenID discovery endpoint, we can use this URL for `server_metadata_url`. Authlib will automatically fetch this `server_metadata_url` to configure the OAuth client for you.

Now we will create a FastAPI application to define a login route.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="secret-string")
```

We need this SessionMiddleware, because Authlib will use `request.session` to store temporary codes and states. The below code which is `/login` endpoint, will redirect you to Google account website.

```
@app.route('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('auth')
    return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri
```

When you grant access from Google website, Google will redirect back to your given `redirect_uri`, which is `request.url_for('auth')`:

```
@app.route('/auth')
async def auth(request: Request):
    token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    user = await oauth.google.parse_id_token(request, token)
    return user
```

The above code will obtain a token which contains access_token and id_token. An id_token contains user info, we just need to parse it to get the login user's information.

Sources: [**Authlib-FastAPI-Google-Login**](https://blog.authlib.org/2020/fastapi-google-login)

Also if you still wanna use Pure FastAPI check this link [**FastAPI OAuth2PasswordRequestForm**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/#oauth2passwordrequestform)